# All elements in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are representable as sum of a square and a cube?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cyclic-groups, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

Is it true that all elements in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are representable as the sum of a square and a cube?

Example: ($n=7$)

$0 \equiv 0^2+0^3 \left( \text{mod } 7 \right)$

$1 \equiv 1^2+0^3 \left( \text{mod } 7 \right)$

$2 \equiv 1^2+1^3 \left( \text{mod } 7 \right)$

$3 \equiv 2^2+3^3 \left( \text{mod } 7 \right)$

$4 \equiv 5^2+0^3 \left( \text{mod } 7 \right)$

$5 \equiv 2^2+4^3 \left( \text{mod } 7 \right)$

$6 \equiv 0^2+6^3 \left( \text{mod } 7 \right)$

It is trivial to see that $0$, $1$, $2$, and $\left( n-1 \right)$ can be represented as the sum of a square and a cube.  This is accomplished when considering the combinations like $\left( 0^2+0^3 \right)$, $\left( 0^2+1^3 \right)$, $\left( 1^2+0^3 \right)$, etc.

How can I prove this?

EDIT:

There is a slightly stronger version which states that all elements can be written as $a^2+b^3$, where $a \ne b$.  I have verified this stronger version up to $n=1000$.

Comment: how do you get $7$ as the sum of a square and a cube in just $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Ryan, the suggestion seems to be that you are doing this in the ring of integers $\pmod n.$ If so, could you display all your solutions for $n=20,$ show all $j \equiv x^2 + y^3 \pmod {20}$ with $1 \leq j \leq 19?$

Comment: @WillJagy I have just displayed my solutions for $n=7$ at your earlier request.  Any reason to prefer $n=20$ over $n=7$?

Comment: No, no important reason.

Comment: By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, it suffices to decide this problem with $n$ a prime or prime power. It is very likely true for all primes, as half the residues are squares, and at least a third of residues are cubes. Less sure about $n=p^2, n=p^3,$ etc.

Comment: Also, representing $n-2$ will not always be obvious.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right.  I was thinking it was somehow implied by symmetry, but it doesn't work because $x^2$ and $x^3$ have different parity.

Comment: @WillJagy If we have a solution modulo $p$, I think we can get solutions modulo $p^k$ from Hensel's lemma. Depending on whether $p\neq2$ or $p\neq3$, hold $x$ or $y$ fixed and lift the other variable. Right?

Comment: There is also a multivariable Hensel lemma.

Comment: This is also 2012 International Mathematical Olympiad Shortlist N7

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I prove it for $n=p$ a prime. After checking the cases $p=2$ and $p=3$ by hand, I suppose that $p>3$. Let $a \in \mathbf F_p$, we want to show that $a$ is the sum of a square and a cube. Without loss of generality we suppose $a \neq 0$.  Let $E_a$ be the curve
$$y^2 = x^3 +a.$$
over $\mathbf F_p$. Since $a \neq 0$, $E_a$ is an elliptic curve over $\mathbf F_p$. We have the following theorem (the so-called *Hasse bound*, or the *Riemann hypothesis for elliptic curves over finite fields*):

> **Theorem** (Artin - Hasse) : Let $E/\mathbf F_p$ be an elliptic curve. Then $$|\#E(\mathbf F_p) - p - 1| \leq 2 \sqrt p.$$

**Corollary**: If $p>3$, then $\#E(\mathbf F_p)>1$, i.e. $E$ has a nontrivial rational point over $\mathbf F_p$.

*Proof*: If $\#E(\mathbf F_p) = 1$ then $p \leq 2 \sqrt p$ implies $p\leq 4$.

**Corollary**: If $p$ is prime, then every element of $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$ is the sum of a cube and a square.

*Proof*: If $(x_0, y_0)$ is a nontrivial point on $E_a$ then $y_0^2 + (-x_0)^3 = a$.

*Remark*: Your other question, concerning the existence of a solution with $x_0 \neq y_0$, can be answered positively using Bézout's theorem. The line $y=x$ intersects $E_a$ in at most $3$ points, so for $p$ large enough, Artin-Hasse still guarantees the existence of a solution with $x_0 \neq y_0$. (I'll let you figure out the right bound on $p$.)

Comment: For prime powers you can show that mod $p$ there is a solution that is not $(0,0)$ if $a \neq 0$ or $p \ge 11$. Then for any lift of $a$ mod $p^n$ you can lift that solution mod $p^n$

Comment: Dear @mercio I think that you are right, but I suppose one might have to be careful for $p=2$ and $p=3$. If you'd like to work out the details, feel free to edit them into my post. Regards,

Comment: The case of primes powers for $p < 11$ needs extra care. A solution covering all prime powers is in my answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/134352/the-modular-arithmetic-contradiction-trick-for-diophantine-equations?rq=1

Comment: @KCd Very nice, thanks!